# Proving the Radius of Circumsphere of a Regular Tetrahedron is $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}s$ for side length $s$

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

> For a regular tetrahedron with side length $s,$ show that the radius of the circumsphere of the tetrahedron is $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}s.$

For starters, I know that the centroid of a tetrahedron splits its medians into ratios of $3:1.$ I took a look at the following link: http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/tetrahedron.htm but I didn't really understand how they got the medians were split by the centroid into ratios of $2:1.$ (I understand that they are considering a $2$ dimensional triangle to prove it but I don't understand how this works). Furthermore, how do we necessarily know the centroid of the tetrahedron is the center of its circumcircle and how do we know that the radius of the circumsphere is $\frac{2}{3}$ of the height? May I have some assistance to understand what they are doing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: All regular tetrahedra are similar and will have the same ratio of side length and radius.  You just have to show it is true for one example.  What is the tetrahedron that would be simplest for these calculations?

Comment: Hmm, alright. Also, I think I understand the $3:1$ and $2:1$ things now. The reason why is because one of them is the height of the whole tetrahedron, while the other is just the height of one of the sides. However, I'm still a little confused on how we know the centroid of the tetrahedron will be the center of the circumscribed circle..

Comment: @DougM Hmm, a regular tetrahedron with side lengths $1?$

Comment: I would pick the tetrahedron with vertexes at $(1,1,1),(-1,-1,1),(1,-1,-1),(-1,1,-1)$

Comment: Just verify, via Pythagoras' theorem, that the centroid has the same distance from all vertices.